# Count number documents from collection inside Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I'm trying to count the number of documents inside an array from a collection.
Below you can see the Schema.

[MongoDB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlTjF.png)

What I want to count is each type of expenseType but since I have this value inside an array I don't know how to build a query to get this value.
The final result should be:
Water: 2 | Wifi: 1

And when I add new Water should be Water:3 and so on.

Below I show what I'm trying to do, but received an error

```
router.get("/getExpense", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  House.aggregate(
    {
      $match: {
        userID: req.user.id,
        expensesHouse: { $elemMatch: { status: "Public" } }
      }
    }
    { $group: { _id: "$Water", price: { $sum: 1 } } }
  ).then(house => {
    console.log(res.json({ house }));
  });
});
```

The res.json is because I send a JSON with the values and fetching to build a chart.

This is the fetch I'm doing.

```
getData();
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("/houses/getExpense", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). It creates intermediary entries that you can group on.

```
House.aggregate(
    {
      $match: {
        userID: req.user.id,
        expensesHouse: { $elemMatch: { status: "Public" } }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$expensesHouse',
    },
    { $group: { _id: "$expensesHouse.expenseType", price: { $sum: 1 } } }
  ).then(house => {
    console.log(res.json({ house }));
  });
```

I've also fixed the last group id.

Comment: It worked! Just changed the 'price' for 'total' and this way makes more sense.